# Pygame Screen Won't Erase Before Each Loop

Tags: python, pygame

I've looked everywhere for an answer and can't seem to figure this out.
Here is the code for where I am actually running the pygame and where I created the car object.
I suspect the problem may have something to do with how I'm feeding in a screen when I create the Car object.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

main:

```
import sys
import pygame
from carObject import Car

# set up display
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(1000, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("jtest")

# color background
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# white background
background.fill(WHITE)
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

# create car
c = Car(background, 475, 650)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # update screen
        pass

    # draw things that are happening
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    c.drawCar()
    c.driveForward()
    c.driveLeft()
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    # if game window is close, end game 
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        break
```

Car object

```
import pygame


class Car:

    def __init__(self, screen, x, y):

        # takes screen to draw to as input
        # takes x and y coordinates for starting position

        self.X = x
        self.Y = y

        # set car color
        self.BODY_COLOR = (0, 0, 255)

        #set tire color
        self.TIRE_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)

        #set headlight color
        self.HEADLIGHT_COLOR = (255, 255, 0)

        # set screen
        self.SCREEN = screen

        # set speed
        self.SPEED = 1




    def drawCar(self):

        # store l and w as variables
        length = 120
        width = 65

        # draw main body
        pygame.draw.rect(self.SCREEN, self.BODY_COLOR, (self.X, self.Y, width, length))

        # draw tires
        # front left tire
        pygame.draw.rect(self.SCREEN, self.TIRE_COLOR, (self.X-10, self.Y+15, 10, 30))
        # front right tire
        pygame.draw.rect(self.SCREEN, self.TIRE_COLOR, (self.X+width, self.Y+15, 10, 30))
        # back left tire
        pygame.draw.rect(self.SCREEN, self.TIRE_COLOR, (self.X-10, self.Y+75, 10, 30))
        # back right tire
        pygame.draw.rect(self.SCREEN, self.TIRE_COLOR, (self.X+width, self.Y+75, 10, 30))

        # draw headlights
        # left headlight
        pygame.draw.circle(self.SCREEN, self.HEADLIGHT_COLOR, (self.X+15, self.Y+12), 7, 0)
        # right headlight
        pygame.draw.circle(self.SCREEN, self.HEADLIGHT_COLOR, (self.X+50, self.Y+12), 7, 0)


    def driveForward(self):
        self.Y -= self.SPEED

    def driveBackward(self):
        self.Y += self.SPEED

    def driveLeft(self):
        self.X -= self.SPEED

    def driveRight(self):
        self.X += self.SPEED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I've solved it!

Had to update the screen.fill from inside the drawCar() function in the Car object

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, but `Car.drawCar()` should draw the car, not fill the screen, or erase the background, etc.  See @martineau's answer, your main-loop is first  drawing the objects, *then* filling the screen with the background.

Answer (score 1):

Change your display loop to this, so it clears the background before drawing the car on it. Since you're drawing on the background and it's the same size as the screen, there's no need fill the screen with `WHITE` each frame.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # if game window is close, end game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # draw things that are happening
#    screen.fill(WHITE)  # Not needed.
    background.fill(WHITE)
    c.drawCar()
    c.driveForward()
    c.driveLeft()

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()
```